# Should we read lambda expressions as "taking" x "return" x+1?

Tags: c#, lambda

I know "goes to" has been suggested in MSDN. I also know it is not a universal usage and also creates confusion to many.

Since basically:
`x => x + 1`

Is equivalent to:
`delegate (int x) { return x + 1; }`

I think the use of the word "return" while reading is paramount to clear what the lambda expression does to everyone.

Is it much better than "goes to" or even worst for some lambda expression uses I am not aware?

Comment: One subtlety is that the lambda expression is only equivalent to the delegate when it is used to create an anonymous function.  LINQ Providers have the ability to interpret the lambda expression in different ways, such as the way the SQL bindings use it to transform lambda expressions into SQL queries.

Comment: lambda's don't always have to return a value.

Comment: I think in the lambda calculus when you're presenting parameter => body, it's read as "parameter is mapped to body," (e.g x=> x * y is "x is mapped to x times y") so I guess it sounds correct to say "mapped to," too. Not sure if anyone does. I usually just read over it (x=> x* y I would read as "x (moment of silence) x times y"

Comment: It got clear that there are very valid uses where "return" is worst than "goes to". However "goes to" is clearly not great... Feels like "returns" is better when something is returned and "goes to" for void. I think I will use it like that.

Comment: @moderators On hold for opinion-based? Answers were very valid and concrete to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what its worth, `=>` was always "such that" to me.

The one issue with saying "returns" is that a lambda, as the shorthand form for *any* anonymous method, does not always return a value. Lambdas are perfectly valid values for `Action<T>` variables for example.

I would probably stick with something more generic like "goes to" or "such that" but if it helps you understand then use what works for you.

Comment: Yes, but using "return" should not add to confusion here because it is also usual for methods that return void to use the return keyword

Comment: @user6788933 Fair, but if you say "taking x returns _list.Add(x)" it sounds a little weird since you know List.Add doesn't return anything

Comment: I agree that "return" doesn't help there.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, "return" is a really bad naming for this. It might be kind of ok in your case, but in general the return has nothing to do with the expression you gave. It is just syntactical sugar that when you only have one statement you can write it without the curly brackets and the statement gets returned anyway.
To make my point clear, consider the following:

```
someList.ForEach(x =>
{
  Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

There is no return or anything similar. I think the term "goes to" describes it way better. If I had to come up with some term, i would probably use "do". Meaning `ForEach x do Console.WriteLine` or in your case for `x => x + 1` it will translate into `x do x + 1`.

Anyway, this is just a personal thought of mine.